# Wordpress Shortcode - Query Portfolio Post Type

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've got in trouble coding a shortcode to query the post type Portfolio. I leave here my shortcode code:

```
function display_custom_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio'
    );
    $string = '';

    $my_query = new wp_query($args);

    if ($my_query - > have_posts()):

        while ($my_query - > have_posts()): $my_query - > the_post(); ?>

    <? php
    $string. = '<div class="latest-post"> < a href = "'.the_permalink().'" > '.the_post_thumbnail().' < /a> < h5 > '.the_title().' < /h5> < span > < i class = "fa fa-plus" > < /i></span >
        < /div>';

    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $string;
}
add_shortcode('ultimos_directorios', 'display_custom_post_type');
```

The query is working, but the OUTPUT is wrong, I paste it here:

```
http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/portfolio/proyecto-1/<img width="650" height="433" src="http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/3.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="3" srcset="http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/3-300x200.jpg 300w, http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/3-200x133.jpg 200w, http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/3.jpg 650w" sizes="(max-width: 650px) 100vw, 650px">Proyecto 1
http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/portfolio/proyecto-2/<img width="650" height="433" src="http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/4.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="4" srcset="http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/4-300x200.jpg 300w, http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/4-200x133.jpg 200w, http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/4.jpg 650w" sizes="(max-width: 650px) 100vw, 650px">Proyecto 2
http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/portfolio/proyecto-3/<img width="650" height="433" src="http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/6.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="6" srcset="http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/6-300x200.jpg 300w, http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/6-200x133.jpg 200w, http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/6.jpg 650w" sizes="(max-width: 650px) 100vw, 650px">Proyecto 3
http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/portfolio/proyecto-4-2/<img width="650" height="433" src="http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/7.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="7" srcset="http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/7-300x200.jpg 300w, http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/7-200x133.jpg 200w, http://threefeelings.com/proyectos/tendencias/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/7.jpg 650w" sizes="(max-width: 650px) 100vw, 650px">Proyecto 4<div class="latest-post">
<a href=""></a>
<h5></h5>
<span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="latest-post">
    <a href=""></a>
    <h5></h5>
    <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="latest-post">
    <a href=""></a>
    <h5></h5>
    <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="latest-post">
    <a href=""></a>
    <h5></h5>
    <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, does not respect the open and close tags, and the URL link deletes the

Any feedback would be really appreciate it. Thanks!!
Frede

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your "$string" to this

```
$string .= '<div class="latest-post"> 
               <a href = "'.get_permalink().'" >'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</a>    
               <h5>'.get_the_title().'</h5><span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
            </div>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much Milap! Works like a charm :)